# How to work with background_fetch plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, background, background-fetch

Returns this error when I trying to run project:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:1.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> - https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> - file:/Users/rustem/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/background_fetch-1.2.0/android/libs/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> -
> - file:/Users/rustem/prometeo/mobile_app/android/app/libs/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find "com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:1.2.0."
> Searched in the following locations:
> -
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/1.2.0/tsbackgroundfetch-1.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :background_fetch

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
My build.gradle:


`
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()


        maven {
        // [required] background_fetch
                url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
            }
        }
    }


`



and another build.gradle:


`
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:1.2.0' 

    }


`
```